# Use .htaccess but ignore URLs beginning with two characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have some RewriteRule commands setup in .htaccess. But, I want anything that begins like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/xq/...
```

...to be ignored. How can I do this without disturbing my other rules? I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/xq$ /xq$1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this rule above others (after `RewriteEngine` directive)

```
RewriteRule ^xq/.*$ - [L]
```

Note: in this case, your htaccess has to be in root folder